# How to pass multiple arguments to procedure in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to pass two string parameters to a Sub, but its not allowing me do that. The approach I have used is given below.

```
Sub callByValue( str1 As String, str2 As String)
MsgBox str1
MsgBox str2

End Sub
```

Calling Macros:

```
 Dim s1, s2 As String
 callByValue(s1,s2)
```

While calling `callByvalue`, it's throwing a compiler error.

Comment: I didn't vote up as you can solve this yourself easily.

Answer (score 24):

You need to remove the brackets

```
callByValue s1, s2
```

Also remember in VBA, When you say `Dim s1, s2 As String` only `s2` will be declared as `String` and the first one will be declared as `Variant`

One more thing that I noticed was that you didn't assign the values of `s1` and `s2` before calling the sub. You will get a blank for both.

For example, do this.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim s1 As String, s2 As String
    s1 = "Blah": s2 = "Blah Blah"
    callByValue s1, s2
End Sub
```

Comment: + 1 for going the extra mile

Comment: +1 As you answered the syntax error of the OP... I didn't see it.

Answer (score 5):

This is better definition for a ByVal call sub.

```
Sub callByValue(ByVal str1 As String, ByVal str2 As String)
  MsgBox str1
  MsgBox str2
End Sub

Sub sof20285505callByVal()
  Dim s1, s2 As String
  callByValue s1, s2
End Sub
```

Comment: + 1 Now After your edit, I can upvote :P

Comment: note that `dim s1, s2 as String` only declares the `s2` as String and `s1` as variant

Comment: @mehow, this is just the quality of my sub. All calling arguments are converted into string before passed into it... You can even call it with a Date type without error.

Comment: implicitly converted. you have to be really careful about implicit conversion ( not THAT careful in VBA, but .Net languages is totally different story ). It's generally a good practice to declare the correct types for your variables

Comment: @mehow, I'm now for all variant type vars, as this is compatible for VBScript.